# Published Android application not showing on Micromax a60 or Samsung GT-i5801 device

Tags: android, google-play

I published one app to the android market, the status of the app is Published with a green tick in my developer account.

I tried to search the app in the market from my micromax a60, but cant find it, than I tried to search it using samsung galaxy GT-i5801 and Sony Ericsson w8 E16i but the same, cant find it.

Then I tried to search on http://market.android.com, but the same cant find it. I see that it shows 1 installs (users).

**Is it still being verified by google? or there is something wrong, if yes, what it could be?**

This is what I see in the setting of the app:

> This application is only available to devices with these features, as
>   defined in your application manifest. Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL
>   LARGE XLARGE Required device features android.hardware.touchscreen

All this are touch screen phones with I guess small and normal screen size.

Here is my manifest file important code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> 
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AppName"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Name" >
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ok, I found it on market.android.com. And in the list of supported devices in my developer account on android market, it does not show micromax a60 or samsung GT-i5801, it does show GT-i5800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check if your device fulfills the criteria for installation (for example screen size, density, android version, etc). If it doesn't then it will not even be able to list in market for that particular device.

2) also make sure you have set **Copy Protection** to **Off** while publishing it. Its my personal experience as one of my app didn't appear on my HTC Desire when i set it to On.

Comment: It seems that my device full fill the creteria, as I tried to push the app from the market website to my device and did download it automatically on my device. When searching it deeper, I did found it listed behind 1000's of app :(